# Using SVN to upload plugin created with gutenberg blocks

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor, svn

I created a plugin using Gutenberg blocks. I have a node_module folder because its using dependencies like Wordpress components.
The plugin folder size is about 100 Mo.

I tried to use SVN to commit and push the files but it's very slow: About 3 hours to commit the files and the post commit never ends ... I waited 2 or 3 hours more, but it seems stuck. I used CLI and RapidSVN and the result is the same.
Do you think I just need to wait more, or is there an issue ?

Regards

Comment: You shouldn't be committing the node_modules directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298668/svn-ignore-like-gitignore for how to ignore in SVN.

Comment: I'm used to ignore node_modules on git repositories, but in that particular case, I think the plugin build files needs the node_modules to work ?
What I upload will be exactly what people will download when installing the plugin, that why I think that without node_modules, it won't work. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, you’re wrong. :) when uploading your plugin you should upload only the production build files. It would be a disaster if every WordPress plugin shipped with its build dependencies. When working in the plugin you reinstall the dependencies locally with `npm install` so that you can build a new version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was not really aware of how build was working (I never took the time to think about it).
I will try and see if its working as expected :)

Comment: Indeed that worked. Thanks !